# How to check whether our Unix flavour cron jobs or not?

Tags: shell-script, cron

```
bash -4.2$ 5 * * * * /user/n0312869/scripts/loop.sh
bash: 5: Command not found
```

Please let me know what needs to be done to schedule a cron job here; I am getting the above mentioned error.

Comment: use `crontab -e`

Comment: crontab entries are not shell commands.

Comment: thanks , i had made used of it, but still im facing issue. I had used crontab -e n0312869 5 * * * * /user/n0312869/scripts/loop.sh , but no luck

Comment: @VimalKumar As Jeff said: `crontab -e` then, when in the editor, add your cron job, save and exit.

Comment: @VimalKumar Don’t forget to click the check mark, to indicate that the problem is now resolved. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You appear to have omitted a key command:

```
crontab -e
```

After that, it will open an editor where you can paste the job definition. Or you will receive a message that you’re not allowed to use cron.

Comment: thanks jeff, i had made used of it, but still im facing issue. I had used crontab -e n0312869  5 * * * *  /user/n0312869/scripts/loop.sh , but no luck

Comment: Two separate steps: crontab -e; then enter the job into the editor; (the save and exit from the editor)